# TS: How to set value when the class have another class as parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript

Update problem :

Hello, I'm new in Angular.

I'm looking for something like this in my array :

```
Object {
   name:Nameless,
   surname {
      newName:Unknown
      nickname {
      myNickname:SS.h77,
      }
   }
}
```

I create 3 class like this as model :

profile.ts

```
import {Surname} from './surname';
    export class Profile{
      name: any;
      surname: Surname;
    }
```

surname.ts

```
import {Nickname} from './nickname';
    export class Surname{
          newName: string;
          nickname: Nickname;
        }
```

nickname.ts

```
export class Nickname{
   nickname: string;
}
```

I want to put a value in newName and nickname, I don't have a problem when I put a value in name (ex: element.name = 'Nameless') but when I want to put a value in newName like this element.surame.newName = 'Unknown', it didn't find 'surname' (same thing for nickname).

```
public profile: Profile;
this.profile= new Profile();
this.profile.name = 'Nameless' // no problem
this.profile.surname.newName = 'Unknown' // don't find surname
this.profile.surname.nickname = 'ss.hh7' // don't find nickname
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and choose an answer if it fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't initialize `Surname` in your `Profile`.

**UPDATE**

Something like this, is ok with you new properties `nickname`:

```
class Nickname{
  nickname: string;
}
class Surname{
  newName: string;
  nickname: Nickname = new Nickname; // <- initialization added
}

class Profile{
  name: any;
  surname: Surname = new Surname; // <- initialization added
}

const profile = new Profile();
profile.name = 'Nameless' 
profile.surname.newName = 'Unknown' 
profile.surname.nickname.nickname = 'ss.hh7' // <- you missed one .nickname 

console.log(profile);
```

Output:

```
Profile: {
  "surname": {
    "nickname": {
      "nickname": "ss.hh7"
    },
    "newName": "Unknown"
  },
  "name": "Nameless"
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, it solved my problem, I tried once again by adding a new class nickname go through Profile->Username->Nickname but it seems the previous solution didn't work and don't find this time nickname but found surname.

(I update my Post to clearly see the result I want with this sample)

Comment: Answer updated :) You missed the attribute `nickname` here `this.profile.surname.nickname = 'ss.hh7' // don't find nickname` and don't forget to initialize object in the class/constructor or before you use them. These initializations are missing in your question.